# Table size limit to do a Broadcast Join in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

The official documentation says that if 1 table is small enough, a broadcast join can be created (which is faster than a Shuffle join): https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-compute#optimize_your_join_patterns

However, it does not indicates the size limit for the small table. Some (old) links on the internet say we no longer do some broadcast join if the small table is higher than 8MB. However, this number seems quite small to me (I compare with Hive where I can have several hundreds of MB in the small table).

Does somebody know this limit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exact value is not published, and it is not a fixed value (depends on types of JOINs and on query plan shape), but it is in order of hundrends of MBs.