# Bigger table on the left during joins

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I was going through some optimizations for BigQuery query and found that the best practice is to have the bigger table of the two tables involved in the join on the left. Why is that and how it makes a difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-compute) says to this:

> When you have a large table as the left side of the JOIN and a small
> one on the right side of the JOIN, a broadcast join is created. A
> broadcast join sends all the data in the smaller table to each slot
> that processes the larger table. It is advisable to perform the
> broadcast join first.

**It is all about the `broadcast join`**

Well think of a large table A with all your customer data and a column country. The table B has to mapping of country to continent and currency. The table A is large and the table B very small.

Therefore, the huge table A is already splitted by BigQuery on several computation node, in BigQuery these are called `slots`. The small table B can be send to each slot. The join does not generate more entries and each slot can work with the data it already has.

If there is a join to the small table B by the large table A. The complete large table A cannot be send to the slot, where table B is located. Therefore, several new slots get alloacted and a copy of table B and a partion of table A is send to them. The join needs to allocate new entries since for a single row in table B, there are several entries in table A which fullfill the join condition.

The 2nd scenario needs much more overhead compuation for allocation and coping a table.

Please see as well: [Table size limit to do a Broadcast Join in BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48952847/table-size-limit-to-do-a-broadcast-join-in-bigquery)